# Passing by Struct pointer is returning wrong value

Tags: c

I am new to C but I am trying to edit a struct in a different function. I can print the value of the struct correctly from the target function `readCoordinate` but when execution returns to the `main` function the values of the struct changes to a seemingly random integers.

This is the full code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
   int  X;
   int  Y;
} Coordinate;

void buff_clr(void)
{
    char junk;
    do{
        junk=getchar();
    }while(junk!='\n');
}

int main()
{
    Coordinate carrierStart = {0,0};

    printf("Input Start coordinate for Carrier (example - B2) \n");
    readCoordinate(&carrierStart);
    printf("%d, %d \n", carrierStart.X, carrierStart.Y);

}

void readCoordinate(Coordinate *cood){
    char str[2];
    scanf("%s",&str);
    buff_clr();

    if (isalpha(str[0]) )
    {
        str[0] = tolower(str[0]);
        findChar(str[0], &cood->X);

        cood->Y = (str[1] - '0') - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n Please Enter Valid Coordinate");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    
    printf("%d, %d \n", cood->X, cood->Y);
    return;
}

void findChar(char find, int *x){
    char vertical_letters[10] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'};

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (find == vertical_letters[i])
        {
            *x = i;
            return;
        }
    }
    *x = -1;
}
```

input of b2 should print 1,1 which is correct in function (readCoordinate) but wrong in Main.

Comment: `str[1]-'0'` your array can only hold 1 input character and terminating 0 byte. If you enter more than 1 character, you access the array out of bounds.

Comment: IMO the culprit is a misunderstanding of the `char str[2];` declaration. What do you think it means, exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part

```c
    char str[2];
    scanf("%s",&str);
```

is wrong because

- `&str` has type `char(*)[2]`, but `%s` in `scanf` expects `char*`. Passing data having the wrong type like this invokes *undefined behavior*.
- `char str[2];` is too short to store 2-character strings like `b2` because there is no room for the terminating null character. You have to allocate enough elements.
- You should specify the maximum length to read (the length of buffer minus one) to prevent buffer overrun.

It should be:

```c
    char str[3];
    scanf("%2s",str);
```

Comment: ...and they should test the return value to make sure anything meaningful has been read into `str[]`, too. Also, they should test `strlen(str)==2` to make sure the input was actually 2-characters long, as expected.